# How does char value stores in memory? For little as well as big endian?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the output for the following code in c language but i don't understand how does it output -80 in little endian machine.

```
char d = 1200;
printf ("%d ", d);
```

Comment: 1200 is likely to be an invalid value for `char`. And your `d` might be stored only in a register, or constant folded by the compiler. At last, it is not a question of endianness, but of `signed char` vs `unsigned char` (and what is the `char` on your system is implementation specific)

Comment: The behaviour is undefined, because `char d` cannot represent `1200`. But what might be happening is that `1200` decimal being `4B0` hex is truncated to 8-bit `B0` hex which because the `char` is signed, is `-80` decimal in two's-complement. The endianness is irrelevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Isn't it just implementation defined rather than undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Endianness has nothing to do with it. I assume you have 8bit `char`. So you try to assign an integer constant to a `char` that doesn't fit, `1200` is `0x4b0`. C converts it by cutting off the most significant bits, the result is `0xb0`. *)

Interpreted as a *signed* number, it's negative (most significant bit set) and has a value of `80` (inverting bits gives `0x4f`, add one for two's complement is `0x50`, in decimal 80).

*) Note that **signed** overflow is actually undefined, so you could get any other result. I just describe what *probably* happens here, assuming your machine uses two's complement for negative numbers. Unsigned overflow would be defined, by cutting of the most significant bits, and again, this isn't a matter of endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Why it specifically becomes `-80` I have no idea.

However, the error occurs because `1200` is too large for the `char` datatype. It is one of the few C primitives that is guaranteed to be a single size, 1 byte. This also means you need not worry about endianness.

As such, the valid range is `-128` to `127`. Attempts to assign variables outside that range are 'implementation defined', according to the standard. Which is to say, the compiler can do what it feels like.

> Section 6.3.1.3 of the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard:
>
> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type [and] the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it, [then] the result is **implementation-defined**.

Comment: The range is allowed to be larger, a `char` *may* have more than 8 bits.

Comment: Strictly speaking the standard only specifies the range `-127` to `127`. If `SCHAR_MIN` was `-128` there was no reason to make the conversion implementation defined.

Comment: It is `-80` because the first 8-bits of `1200` are `10110000` which as a *signed* value is `-80` or `176` as an *unsigned* value.